# nodejs googlephotos fails to upload with "Authentication session is not defined"

Tags: node.js, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, google-photos-api

I've got some code based on the samples given at the [googlephotos](https://github.com/roopakv/google-photos#readme) documentation.  I basically just took the code provided as-is and modified it to fill in my client id, secrets, etc. generate a URL which I then paste into my brower, and after clicking through to authorize my app I copy the code it gives me and using it to construct a new Photos object.

I tried setting up my scopes as:

```
const scopes = [
    Photos.Scopes.READ_ONLY,
    Photos.Scopes.SHARING,
    Photos.Scopes.APPEND_ONLY
];
```

But I also tried:

```
const scopes = [
    Photos.Scopes.APPEND_ONLY
];
```

and

```
const scopes = [
    Photos.Scopes.READ_AND_APPEND
];
```

I am able to to get back auth tokens which I can use to build a new Photos object.  I try to upload something like this:

```
const response = await photos.mediaItems.upload("", "test.mp4", "/home/michael/test/test.mp4", "Test Upload");
```

I get this error along with a stack trace which seems useless:

> (node:13122) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: StatusCodeError: 401 - "{\n  \"code\": 16,\n  \"message\": \"Authentication session is not defined.\"\n}"

I have granted append permission, which is all that should be for this to have the proper authorization, yet it still fails!  What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

The documentation isn't super-specific about exactly what "auth_token" you are supposed to pass, merely saying:

`const photos = new Photos(your_google_auth_token);`

without defining what `your_google_auth_token` is or where it comes from. Google's [own documentation](https://developers.google.com/photos/library/guides/upload-media) for the upload API just says `oauth2-token` which isn't helpful in getting to the bottom of what this value should be.

In the same code for getting the tokens it just says:

```
const {tokens} = await oauth2Client.getToken(code)

// The token from above can be used to initialize the photos library.
```

This error occurs when you naively plug the tokens you get into the constructor like so:

```
const photos = new Photos(auth_token)
```

Instead, what you need to do is plug the `access_token` field of the tokens like this:

```
const photos = new Photos(auth_token.access_token)
```